# Excel multi-column averages

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I need to take the value in two data columns A and C, get a percentage by dividing the current value of columns A and C by the top value (which is a total), and then average the two percentages and spit them out in column D. For example D2 should be (100(226/508)+(100(218/490))) / 2). I'd prefer to do this with one equation - is it possible?

```
A       B       C         D
1       508     490

2       226     44.49%    218

3       229     45.08%    221
```

Comment: Could you make that a bit clearer: reformat the example table for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The formula you want is

```
=(100*A2/A$1 + 100 *C2/C$1)/2
```

and the select all of column D downwards and then edit->fill down

The relative reference A2 will change in each row to the new row but A$1 is an absolute reference and will stay as the value in row 1.

You can also do this with array formula that do the fill down for you. See [MS article](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/introducing-array-formulas-in-excel-HA001087290.aspx)

Comment: Edit -> Fill Down did the trick beautifully, Leniel. Thanks a million.